# Replacing an F# loop over a mutable variable by an immutable approach

Tags: recursion, primes, f#, immutability

Consider:

```
        let mutable m' = m
        while m' % i = 0L do
            m' <- m' / i
```

I've refactored it into:

```
        let m' =
            let rec exhaust m =
                if m % i = 0L then exhaust (m/i)
                else m
            exhaust m
```

but it's pretty obvious to me that the original code was way more concise and clear than this last one. Is there anything simple and clear that I'm missing regarding this refactor?

The full algorithm:

```
(* Calculates all the prime factors of a given integer *)
let primeFactors x =
    let rec primeFactors' = function
        | (m, _, r) when m = 1L -> r
        | (m, i, r) ->
            let mutable m' = m
            while m' % i = 0L do
                m' <- m' / i
            primeFactors' (m', (i+1L), (if m <> m' then i::r else r))
    List.rev (primeFactors' (x, 2L, []))
```

Comment: It only looks clearer to the non-functional eye. The second version looks cleaner to me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it this way

```
let rec exhaust m i =
    match m % i with
    | 0L -> exhaust (m / i) i
    | _ -> m
```

Not a huge improvement, but I think it's idiomatic. Now let's look at `primeFactors`:

```
let primeFactors x =
    let rec primeFactors' = function
        | (m, _, r) when m = 1L -> r
        | (m, i, r) ->
            let m' = exhaust m i
            primeFactors' (m', (i+1L), (if m <> m' then i::r else r))
    List.rev (primeFactors' (x, 2L, []))
```

Let's get rid of the `when`:

```
let primeFactors x =
    let rec primeFactors' = function
        | (1L, _, r) -> r
        | (m, i, r) ->
            let m' = exhaust m i
            primeFactors' (m', (i+1L), (if m <> m' then i::r else r))
    List.rev (primeFactors' (x, 2L, []))
```

And tidy up a little

```
let primeFactors x =
    let rec primeFactors' = function
        | 1L, _, r -> r
        | m, i, r ->
            let m' = exhaust m i
            primeFactors' (m', i + 1L, if m <> m' then i::r else r)
    primeFactors' (x, 2L, []) |> List.rev
```

I know the style in F# is for short variable names, and I'm all for that for the most part, but I think in this case we can/should make them a bit clearer.

```
let rec exhaust n factor =
    match n % factor with
    | 0L -> exhaust (n / factor) factor
    | _ -> n

let rec primeFactors' = function
    | 1L, _, factors -> factors
    | n, factor, factors ->
        let m = exhaust n factor
        primeFactors' (m, factor + 1L, if n <> m then factor::factors else factors)

let primeFactors n =
    primeFactors' (n, 2L, []) |> List.rev
```

Comment: "Let's get rid of the when" You couldn't have guessed it, but I have it there as I've originally designed the function to accept bigints instead of longs, and that was an artifact I forgot to remove.

Comment: I agree that pattern matching is both more idiomatic and more clear, in thenexhaust function.

Comment: And I totally agree with you about the variable names. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's been said that "recursion is the goto of functional programming". 
If you don't get the tail recursion right, your stack can explode, so I like to use alternatives like `fold` if I can.

In this case, how about using [the under-appreciated `unfold` (PDF)](http://www.fing.edu.uy/inco/cursos/proggen/Articulos/unfold.pdf.gz) instead?

```
let rec exhaust n factor =
    match n % factor with
    | 0L -> exhaust (n / factor) factor
    | _ -> n

let nextFactor (n,factor) =
    if n = 1L then 
        None  // None means terminate the unfold
    else         
        let m = exhaust n factor
        let maybePrimeFactor = if n <> m then Some factor else None
        let newState = m, (factor + 1L)
        Some (maybePrimeFactor,newState) // Some means keep the unfold going

let primeFactors n =    
    (n, 2L) 
    |> Seq.unfold nextFactor // this will contain Nones for non-prime factors 
    |> Seq.choose id         // so filter them out
```

No recursion in the prime factor generation now, but because it uses seq rather than list it is probably not as performant as the list version.

And because the "looping" is separated from the "processing", some people might consider this code somewhat cleaner as a result.

Comment: I've had my unfold phase until I finally started realizing that in most cases my code was just getting awkward to look at, at best, and that it often required post-processing (as you did with Seq.choose). Also, a big concern regarding your version performance, as you referred.